# How to set user input to be capitalised

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to access the https://docs.openaq.org/ api and I have created a search function, where you can type the name of the city which should set a state which then is added to the url used to the data. However the user input must be capitalised and I can't seem to get it to work.

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';
import Axios from 'axios';
import Button from '../UI/Button';
import SearchedCity from './SearchedCity';

const Search = () => {
    const [searchedCity, setSearchedCity] = useState('');
    
    const [city, setCity] = useState();
    const [airQuality, setAirQuality] = useState();
    const [dateAndTime, setDateAndTime] = useState();
    const [latitude, setLatitude] = useState();
    const [longitude, setLongitude] = useState();
    const [country, setCountry] = useState();

    const searchCity = async () => {
        try{
            const url = `https://api.openaq.org/v1/measurements?country=GB&city=${searchedCity}`;
            const res = await Axios.get(url);
            
            console.log(res)
            
        } catch (error) {
            alert('Please learn to spell');
        }
    }
    const handleSubmit = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        searchCity();
        console.log({searchedCity})
    }
    const handleChange = (e) => {
        let userInput = e.target.value;
        userInput.charAt(0).toUpperCase()
        console.log(userInput)
        setSearchedCity(userInput)
        
        
        
    }
    return (
        <div>
            <form onSubmit={handleSubmit} className="form" >
                <label>
                    <input type="text" placeholder="Search for a UK city" onChange={handleChange}  />
                    <Button handleSubmit={handleSubmit}></Button>
                </label>
                
            </form>
            <SearchedCity city={city} ></SearchedCity>
        </div>
    );
};

export default Search;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this

```
userInput = userInput.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + userInput.slice(1);
```

It will capitalise the first letter but keep the rest of the string same.

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is that you don't set the value after changing that character.
So, just do that.

```
const handleChange = (e) => {
    let userInput = e.target.value;
    userInput = userInput.charAt(0).toUpperCase()
    console.log(userInput)
    setSearchedCity(userInput)
}
```